# How can Many2many field in Odoo be searchabel in search view?

Tags: python, odoo

Field in models:
`employee_ids = fields.Many2many('hr.employee', string='Employees*', domain="[('id', '!=', manager_id)]")`

search in view:

```
            <field name="name">training.request.filter</field>
            <field name="model">training.request</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <search string="Search Training Requests">
                <field name='employee_ids'/>
                </search>
```

Comment: What is the problem you're getting? There are already some examples in Odoo itself. For example tags on leads (crm.lead), which works like a charm.

Comment: The problem is that it gives an error and I cant search name as an employee_ids field because its a many2many field. Can u explain what is a tags on leads?

Comment: It's a many2many field ;-) tag_ids IIRC

Comment: Oh and please add your error message/traceback to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that as below:

```
<field name="employee_ids" string="Employee" filter_domain="[('employee_ids', 'child_of', self)]"/>
```

or

```
<field name="employee_ids" string="Employee" filter_domain="[('employee_ids', 'ilike', self)]"/>
```